# Laminate to tile transition

Tags: flooring, tile, laminate-floor, transition

I am laying my floor but I have a transition that I need help with, I am going from laminate to tile but the tile is much bigger. I have attached a drawing of the 2 different materials and I am looking to see what people might recommend on doing

[image: Floor transitions]

Comment: Welcome.  A couple questions. How wide is the gap? What is the material of the subfloor (plywood, concrete, ...)?  When you stand on the new floor at its edge at the gap, how much does the underlayment pad compress?

Answer (score 1):

The transition problem that you depict is often solved with a trim strip made of wood that can look something like as shown below. It is often possible to purchase a similar molding and re-saw it into necessary shape. However your could also make your own from a length of the appropriate hardwood using a combination of a table saw and a router table.

[image]

Comment: Is the lip on the tile side needed ? I was thinking of butting it up against the tile. That way it it flows a little nicer.Given the thickness of the tile I was hoping that the edge could not need as much protection,

Comment: You would not need to have the transition molding come up over the tile. It could butt up against the edge as you suggest. I think there are some factors to consider. First off for a "butt to the tile" approach I would have the molding come just at or tiny little amount above the edge of the tile. This will help protect the tile edge from chipping. Many tiles are sloped or rounded right at the edge so the wood trim a little proud of the surface would not be noticed when walking over it. Now all that said do evaluate how even the tiles are along edges and across tops (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) near the edge. If there is more than a nominal amount of variation it may turn out that the TEE molding overlapping the tile may lead to a cleaner look.